# Claudia.js Auto generated lambda function not displaying on AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, claudiajs, claudia.js

So I have created a restAPI backend with express.js and have used claudia.js to upload my endpoints to lambda functions and everything went smoothly. The end points work as expected and return the correct information. My only issue is that when I go to my aws console I do not see the lambda functions that were created. I am not sure where this end point is being hosted. Has anyone else had this issue when working with claudia.js?

Comment: I'm having the same issue! Did you find a solution?

Comment: Same issue. I assume we just have to wait

Comment: It's been a few days and it's still not appearing. Not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your `claudia.json` file you should see something like:

```
  "lambda": {
    "role": "example-role",
    "name": "example-test",
    "region": "us-west-2"   
  },
```

Being `us-west-2` **Oregon**